# HTTP Error 502.3 - Bad Gateway - The operation timed out

Tags: node.js, asp.net-mvc, iis

I'm using node.js and turf.js for processing big data of polygons while AST.NET MVC for the UI but I'm getting an error `HTTP Error 502.3 - Bad Gateway` when the timeout reaches 2 minutes while the node.js is still processing.

I use IIS to access my node.js
this is the web.config

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>                 
            <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:5000/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule2" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:5000/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
<system.web>
<compilation debug="false" />
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="1000" />
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Instead of using ARR, you might consider hosting Node.js web apps on IIS using HttpPlatformHandler, https://halfblood.pro/running-nodejs-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/

Comment: @LexLi Hello, I tried your solution and it works but I don't want to put the port number like localhost:8099 when calling the node app instead I want to call it like localhost/testapi. Any idea how to accomplish it? Thank you

Comment: Then instead of enabling HttpPlatformHandler on a site that monitors `localhost:8099` you should enable it on an IIS application that matches `localhost/testapi`, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis